# How would I iterate over a Pandas Series and compare it to single float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I'm wondering if it's possible to check and see if the result of a calculation between two tables can be used with comparison operators.

Lets say I have two dataframes.

#### DF

```
| user_id | col1| col2| col3| col4| check |
|---------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|
| 100     |  1  |  2  |  1  |  0  |   5   |
| 200     |  2  |  4  |  0  |  2  |   5   |
```

#### DF2

```
| user_id | col1| col2| col3| col4| check |
| 300     |  3  |  6  |  2  |  0  |   5   |
| 400     |  4  |  8  |  0  |  4  |   5   |
```

For each user in df, I loop through each user in df2. I then want to add their col1 values, and see if they are greater than the number 5. If so, a 'greater than 5' should be returned.If not, 'less than 5' should be returned.

This is how I would imagine the syntax to look, but it doesn't work.

```py
for a in df.user_id:
    for b in df2.user_id:
        if df.col1 + df.col2 > df.check:
            print('Greater than 5')
        else:
            print('Less than 5')
```

I get a ValueError:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What's the logic behind this, and how would comparing iterated items to single value work?

Also, aside from being a static value vs an iterable series, is there a difference for using the df.check column value vs an int(5) in the for loop? What kind of effect does this have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should maybe switch to a more relational approach. The way I would proceed is:

```
df_result = (pd.concat([df, df2], axis=0)
             .assign(greater_than_check = lambda d: (d.col1 + d.col2)>d.check))
```

Users with `col1` + `col2` greater than `check`:

```
df_result.loc[lambda d: d.greater_than_check, "user_id"]
```

Comment: This works! As a follow up question, if I had over 500 million rows, would this be as efficient as an iterative process kicking out users that return false? One issue I'm facing is larger datasets that are causing memory issues - scaling the datasets down/back isnt really an option. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, definitely. You should drop that users that you don't need to keep in the data by assigning this last expression to df_result: `df_result = df_result.loc[lambda d: d.greater_than_check, "user_id"]`. 
If it works for you, please don't forget to mark my answer as "accepted" :D

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot! Might have more questions though haha. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
for a in df:
    for b in df2:
        if df.loc[a,"col1"] + df2.loc[b,"col1"] > df.loc[a,"check"]:
            print('Greater than 5')
        else:
            print('Less than 5')
```

Before, you were adding and comparing an entire column to another entire column. Instead, look at the row index of one column using [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).